# Can I delete older SMS logs from the twilio server via the user console

Tags: twilio

Can I delete older SMS logs from the twilio server via the user console? I only need about 30 days worth of records.

==============================================================

Update: following @philnash's suggestion, I was able to delete all messages older than 30 days with the following C# code:

```
    using Twilio;
    void deleteMessages(int num_days)
    {
        var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
        bool done;
        do
        {
            done = false;
            var request = new MessageListRequest();
            request.Count = 1000;  // this is all you can get per request
            request.DateSent = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-num_days);
            request.DateSentComparison = ComparisonType.LessThanOrEqualTo;

            var messages = twilio.ListMessages(request);
            if (messages.Messages.Count < 1000) done = true;
            foreach (var message in messages.Messages)
            {
                twilio.DeleteMessage(message.Sid);
            }
        } while (!done);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I can't find a way to delete logs from the console, however you can absolutely write some code to do so. Here's an example to delete messages older than 30 days in Ruby:

```
require "twilio-ruby"
require "date"

client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"], ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"])
messages = client.messages.list("DateSent<" => (Date.today - 30).to_s)
while !messages.empty?
  messages.each { |message| message.delete }
  messages = messages.next_page
end
```

Let me know if that sort of thing helps.

Comment: Yes, thanks!  I will have to do a little head-scratching to get a python equivalent but I get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by writing a javascript code and run using nodejs

```
var twilio = require('twilio');
var accountSid = 'your sid'; // Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/console
var authToken = 'your token';   // Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/console

var twilio = require('twilio');
var client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages.each(messages => messages.remove().then().done());
```